# Required Field Validator for drop down list Dynamic

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddTitle" runat="server" DataTextField="TitleName" DataValueField="TitleId"ValidationGroup="t1">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="ReqDropDnw" ControlToValidate="ddTitle" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="t1" InitialValue="<-- Select Title-->" ErrorMessage="Please Select Title">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

I have used this but it's not working, can I have a proper solution for it
My dropdown list is a dynamic.

Comment: what is the problem you are getting...?

Comment: validatior is not working !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use like this way...

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Text="Select One" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="abc" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="xyz" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Now you can use required field validator for this dropdownlist.....

Comment: if TitleId is numeric in that case you can use reqularexpression validation with this expression ^\d{5}$ . here 5 is the limit of numeric characters limit.

Comment: ma drop down is getting fill from data base 
dynamically m getting d values so i cant use list

Answer (score 0):

After binding data from DB you can use add one empty item to list like:

```
ddTitle.Items.Insert(0, "");
```

And now Required field validatior will work for this dropdown.